# Randomly change audio src on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

(I'm a relative newbie to JS and jQuery, so pardon any indiscretions!)

I'm trying to randomly change the src in an audio element when I hover over other elements. I've piecemealed something together and got it to work via a button with inline JS (thanks to an answer I can't find at the moment), but can't get it to work on .hover.

[I have this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/D8Ln7/)

JS:
    function sounds(){

```
var rand = [
    'http://thejazz.ninja/sounds/v.mp3',
    'http://thejazz.ninja/sounds/w.mp3',
    'http://thejazz.ninja/sounds/x.mp3',
    'http://thejazz.ninja/sounds/y.mp3',
    'http://thejazz.ninja/sounds/z.mp3'];

var randSound = rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];

var player=document.getElementById('player');
var sourceMp3=document.getElementById('sourceMp3');

sourceMp3.src='' + randSound + '';

   player.load();
   player.play();
}

$('.box').click(sounds); // this doesn't work...
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="player" autoplay>
  <source id="sourceMp3" src="" type="audio/mp3" />
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p>
    <button onclick='sounds()'> Load Sound</button> <!-- THIS works -->
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#aee;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to selector onload or onDomReady from second dropdown in the Frame and Extension Tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.box').click(sounds);
```

There is no `.box` when this is execute. Wrap it with [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3):

```
$(function(){                       //this function will be executed when DOM is
    $('.box').click(sounds);        //ready to be manipulated (!= onload)
});
```

or in jsFiddle you can choose "onLoad"/"onDomready" on the left instead of "No wrap - in <head>": http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/D8Ln7/6/

---

About the "hover" part, change click to [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/):

```
$(function(){
    $(".box").mouseenter(sounds);
});
```

Do not use `.hover`. There is a method [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2) in jQuery, but this will not work in this case since it doesn't match what you are trying to do. Quoting the documentation:

> [.hover] will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

An updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/D8Ln7/8/

Comment: Bro i think you deserve an up vote. mouse enter is a good idea!

Comment: mouseenter is a good idea! all the other solutions (so far) with the exception of @nathvarun play another sound as soon as the mouse is moved again. I lack the knowledge to know which one would ultimately be better

Comment: @leftside - Since `.hover` is a shorthand for `.on("mouseenter mouseleave")`, it's better to just use `.mouseenter` to avoid attaching unnecessary empty functions to `mouseleave`. Other than that, they are pretty much the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hover(sounds);    
});
```

You must make sure html elements are rendered when add events for them.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the DOM to be loaded before calling the hover method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".box" ).hover(
  function() {
    sounds();      
  }, function() {
      //hover out 
  });
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/D8Ln7/7/)

Comment: thanks for this answer, it was a close second until i saw Derek's explanation and answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.box').click(sounds);
```

instead of abouve call use must try

```
    $(document).ready(
              function() {
                  $('.box').click(function(){
                  sounds();
                 });

               });
```

and to make call on hover you need to call onBlur event

```
           <button onblur='sounds()'> Load Sound</button>
```